# Are there general recommendations for mugs?

Tags: equipment, cup

Is there a general consensus on what some of the best mugs out there are in terms of keeping (drip/pour-over) coffee warm, style, and flavor? Ceramic? Double-walled glass?

Comment: Could you please see [this question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2600/how-much-does-the-shape-of-the-drinking-vessel-change-the-flavor/2601#2601)? Somewhat more generic in terms, but mostly cover the similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Ceramic is more porous than glass, so a ceramic mug insulates better than regular glass and thus keep the coffee hotter, but [double-walled glass insulates even better than ceramic](https://youtu.be/h25CiDT_tL8).

A porous mug might exchange molecules from one cup to the next. (Is there experimental data on that?)

Answer (score 0):

From experience, glass or ceramic is usually better, but eitherway whatever kind of cup you use, make sure to warm it before pouring your coffee in it.